# Weird behaviour when assigning material to specific faces

Tags: rendering, materials

[image: assigned faces]

I'm following a guitar tutorial, and I created a material for the sides of the guitar. I assigned it to the sides, but in rendered view I get a band of the other material above and below the side material.

[image: rendered view]

Any Idea why this is happening? Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:** [.blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13P7IAjA2dNYaahn54r74lKPeJJirClcy)

Comment: Subdivision surface modifier is the problem. Select the *side* material faces in edit mode and expand (Ctrl Numpad+), then assign them to the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subsurf modifier is smoothing the edges which allowed the above material to bleed out to the sides.

Add two loop cuts to the sides to fix it. (shortcut ctrl+R, then sroll up once)
[image]